# How do I get enough people to notice my sandbox post?

Tags: support, sandbox

In the previous sandboxes, it was suggested that if you had 3 upvotes on your sandbox submission, it was ready to go.

I have written a few sandbox posts recently. Of these, all have been commented on and one has had 4 votes  - this is clearly enough. However, two have had 0 votes and two have had 1 vote.

I have occasionally bumped the posts in chat, but this seems to have had little or no effect.

**How do I make more people notice my sandbox submission? Do I need to?**

Comment: It's not a very good suggestion anyway. I've seen sandbox answers which got 4 upvotes within an hour of posting, no comments, but had major problems.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, posts with *problems* are more likely to generate comments and/or votes. I'll admit, while browsing the sandbox I often forget to upvote and simply move on to the next post, looking for potential issues.

Another reason might be that if I *see* something wrong, I'm confident in saying there's an issue. If I *don't* see something wrong, that doesn't mean there isn't. Maybe someone else will see the problem and my upvote would encourage an early transfer. I'm not saying this is right (or that I consciously think this while browsing), but it's something I may try to pay attention to more in the future.

If your post has been in the sandbox for a certain amount of time and you're confident it meets the standards, I'd say go for it. If there *are* comments, obviously try to address them first (and maybe reset the timer). "A certain amount of time" is ambiguous on purpose, but I would say 2-3 days without comment seems okay.

Comment: I recently commented on a sandbox post where the author was complaining about not having comments. My comment basically said "this looks fine, and most of us only comment if there are problems"